# What is the daily limit for comment votes?

Tags: support, votes

I just tried to vote a comment, but I got the following message.

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 8 hours.

Does that mean there is a limit for the comment votes, or does the message simply mean I can vote comments when I have not reached the daily limit for question/answer votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. If I am not awfully mistaken, it is still at 30 comment votes per UTC day (at least that's where [this old blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/) puts it, and I can't remember it having been raised or lowered since).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, RegDwight. What happens if I use all the daily votes for questions/answers? As far as I remember, I didn't vote 30 comments; could it be that once I have used all the question votes I cannot anymore vote for comments too?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That would be a bug in my book. But I have never run into it myself, on any site of the network...

Comment: Thank you again. I will check this when I can vote again. Maybe I can be wrong, and I did really voted on 30 comments; I would be surprised if I voted 30 comments though, as it is something exceptional.

Comment: I was clearly wrong: the limit exists, and it is separated from the voting limit for questions. It just happened that I reached the limit for comment votes, and then tried to vote another comment after I reached the vote limit for questions.

Answer (score 2):

I fairly commonly reach my vote limit on answers/questions, and as far as I recall, I'm still able to upvote comments when that happens. So it seems there are separate vote limits on comments and on questions/answers.